# Webview 4.4 settings custom user agent string

Tags: android, android-webview

Currently I am using custom user agent string for the webview to send limited information to websites loaded in webview. As per Andropid documentation:  http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/migrating.html#UserAgent

Is it necessary to include **Chrome/30.0.0.0** ?

Comment: The docs only say that the user agent of 4.4 webview has changed, so if you host websites that serve content based on the UA string, you have to check for this new useragent to correctly identify kitkat devices. Your use case seems the opposite: You just include stuff in the UA string, so there's nothing to be done in this case.

Comment: @rupps Yes, I am customizing UA so that third party websites(loaded in my WebView) couldn't sniff/retrieve much device information. So, I guess it is okay to avoid Chrome/30.0.0.0. Right ?

Comment: absolutely, if those are your intentions, but i'd recommend to include at least something typical in the UAString if the 3rd party websites are outside of your control because many sites filter funky uastrings with the robots.txt file

Comment: @rupps You are right but I am using standard UA string.